# Increasing VMWare Hard Drive Space Server 22.04LTS?

Tags: server, partitioning, vmware

o)  I have created a 40GB virtual disk in VMWare Fusion Pro.

o)  My partition /dev/sda3 is already 40GB according to gparted (see pic)

o)  However, df -H still only shows 20GB

What do I need to do?

```
df -H
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              513M  1.7M  512M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   20G  7.4G   11G  41% /
tmpfs                              2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.1G  134M  1.8G   7% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.2G  5.5M  1.2G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              513M  4.1k  513M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Thanks!

[gparted partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpOvT.png)

Comment: You opted for LVM so you need to use LVM tools.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I find it weird that it doesn't work with gparted. Because of your tip I managed to increase the patition! If you would have answered instead of writing a comment I would have upvoted you. Thank you.